# Appending Nested Struct From Mongo Collection Cursor

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm running into an issue appending a nested struct to an array.

Both have different nested values but when appending the last struct it overwrites the first nested struct.

Here is a simple example of the concept. (I tried to replicate appending nested structs but its working fine) https://play.golang.org/p/PseTHzV33uL

Here are the structs in my actual code

```golang
type Initiative struct {
    OID          primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"json:"id,omitempty"`
    Cid          string             `json:"cid"`
    Name         string             `json:"name"`
    Description  string             `json:"description"`
    ProductName  string             `json:"product_name"`
    ProductId    string             `json:"product_id"`
    Quarter      string             `json:"quarter"`
    Year         string             `json:"year"`
    CustomFields []NestedField            `json:"custom_fields"`
}

type NestedField struct {
    Id    string `json:"id"`
    Cid   string `json:"cid"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Type  string `json:"type"`
    Form  string `json:"form"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type InitiativeResponse struct {
    ErrorCode        string       `json:"error_code,omitempty"`
    ErrorDescription string       `json:"error_description,omitempty"`
    Message          string       `json:"message,omitempty"`
    Payload          []Initiative `json:"payload,omitempty"`
}
```

and this is my function.

```golang
func GetInitiativesFromDB(d *database.MongoDB, cid string) (response InitiativeResponse, err error) {
    filter := bson.M{"cid": cid}
    cur, err := d.Database.Collection(INITIATIVECOLLECTION).Find(context.Background(), filter, options.Find())
    fmt.Printf("%#v", cur)
    if err != nil {
        return response, errors.ErrorResponse{"No initiatives were found", 404}
    }
    var initiative Initiative
    for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
        err := cur.Decode(&initiative)
        if err != nil {
            return response, errors.ErrorResponse{"No initiatives were found", 404}
        }
        response.Payload = append(response.Payload, initiative)
        fmt.Printf("%#v", response.Payload)
    }
    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        return response, errors.ErrorResponse{"No initiatives were found", 404}
    }
    _ = cur.Close(context.Background())
    return response, nil
}
```

This is what I found from printing the values of the the array after appending the first and second time.

Notice that the first time the `NestedField`s have different values than after appending the second time.

First Append

```
[]api.Initiative{
    api.Initiative{
        OID:primitive.ObjectID{0x5d, 0xd9, 0x3f, 0x96, 0xd2, 0xc6, 0xb2, 0x95, 0x19, 0xd2, 0xbf, 0x98}, 
        Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
        Name:"1", 
        Description:"", 
        ProductName:"", 
        ProductId:"", 
        Quarter:"", 
        Year:"", 
        CustomFields:[]api.NestedField{
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5db8ec9fee8040e9b6dfad87", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"Test", 
                Type:"text", 
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:"ggg"}, 
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5dba0bcedf9cbf185683ecca", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"Kylie", 
                Type:"text", 
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:"ggg"}, 
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5dd71d2af20bea1fef4564eb", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"asdfasdf", 
                Type:"text", 
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:"ggg"}}}}
```

Second Append

```
[]api.Initiative{
    api.Initiative{
        OID:primitive.ObjectID{0x5d, 0xd9, 0x3f, 0x96, 0xd2, 0xc6, 0xb2, 0x95, 0x19, 0xd2, 0xbf, 0x98}, 
        Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
        Name:"1", 
        Description:"", 
        ProductName:"", 
        ProductId:"", 
        Quarter:"", 
        Year:"", 
        CustomFields:[]api.NestedField{
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5db8ec9fee8040e9b6dfad87", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"Test", 
                Type:"text", 
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:"aaa"}, 
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5dba0bcedf9cbf185683ecca", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"Kylie", 
                Type:"text", 
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:"aaa"}, 
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5dd71d2af20bea1fef4564eb", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"asdfasdf", 
                Type:"text", 
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:""}}}, 
    api.Initiative{
        OID:primitive.ObjectID{0x5d, 0xd9, 0x3f, 0x9f, 0xd2, 0xc6, 0xb2, 0x95, 0x19, 0xd2, 0xbf, 0x99}, 
        Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
        Name:"2", 
        Description:"", 
        ProductName:"", 
        ProductId:"", 
        Quarter:"", 
        Year:"", 
        CustomFields:[]api.NestedField{
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5db8ec9fee8040e9b6dfad87", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"Test", 
                Type:"text", 
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:"aaa"}, 
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5dba0bcedf9cbf185683ecca", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"Kylie", 
                Type:"text", 
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:"aaa"}, 
            api.NestedField{
                Id:"5dd71d2af20bea1fef4564eb", 
                Cid:"5d8502a2a284b46f3621f389", 
                Name:"asdfasdf", 
                Type:"text",
                Form:"initiative", 
                Value:""}}}}
```

And the result of printing cur

```
&mongo.Cursor{
    Current:bson.Raw(nil), 
    bc:(*driver.BatchCursor)(0xc000204000), 
    batch:(*bsoncore.DocumentSequence)(nil), 
    registry:(*bsoncodec.Registry)(0xc0000ee070), 
    clientSession:(*session.Client)(0xc0001f40c0), err:error(nil)}
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Could you: 1. change `fmt.Println(response.Payload)` to `fmt.Printf("%#v",reponse.Payload)`? 2. Add the output to your question as actual code, and not an image (if the image becomes unavailable, your question becomes meaningless)? 3. Add the output of `db.yourcollection.find({"cid":cid})` to your question as well?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I just made those changes. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I was referring to the output of the mongo shell in order to check the fields and draw a difference between them and your expected output ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when I moved `var initiative Initiative` inside the loop, it worked fine.

```
func GetInitiativesFromDB(d *database.MongoDB, cid string) (response InitiativeResponse, err error) {
    filter := bson.M{"cid": cid}
    cur, err := d.Database.Collection(INITIATIVECOLLECTION).Find(context.Background(), filter, options.Find())
    fmt.Printf("%#v", cur)
    if err != nil {
        return response, errors.ErrorResponse{"No initiatives were found", 404}
    }
    for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
        var initiative Initiative
        err := cur.Decode(&initiative)
        if err != nil {
            return response, errors.ErrorResponse{"No initiatives were found", 404}
        }
        response.Payload = append(response.Payload, initiative)
        fmt.Printf("%#v", response.Payload)
    }
    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        return response, errors.ErrorResponse{"No initiatives were found", 404}
    }
    _ = cur.Close(context.Background())
    return response, nil
}
```